# Introjs is not highlighting the fuse-sidebar elements

Tags: javascript, css, angular, intro.js

I have created an angular project for which I am using [fuse-sidebar](http://angular-material.fusetheme.com/documentation/components/sidebar).
I am also using [introjs](https://introjs.com). That is working fine but this is not highlighting the elements that are inside fuse-sidebar.

This is how it looks for elements inside `fuse-sidebar`

[image]

And this is how for the elements outside the fuse-sidebar

[image]

for fuse elements there is highligher but the element is not shown in the highlight area like in the second photo that is for element that is outside the fuse-sidebar.

What could be the issue?

the html is like this

```
<fuse-sidebar></fuse-sidebar>
<div>other elements</div>
```

For div the `z-index` was 1001 so I have set the same to `fuse-sidebar`. But not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was CSS conflict. `fuse-bar` itself was setting

```
-webkit-transform: translateX(0) !important;
transform: translateX(0) !important;
```

So I need to unset `transform` property

```
fuse-sidebar.locked-open.introjs-fixParent {
    -webkit-transform: unset !important;
    transform: unset !important;
}
```

this solved my problem.